# bash command XOR ^ anothercommand

Tags: linux, bash, operators, delimiter, logical-operators

In the example below:

```
w ^ ls
```

what's the expected behaviour of the XOR operator in shell?

So when we enter

```
command ^ anothercommand
```

what triggers `anothercommand` to run (if it will execute at all)?

Comment: If it *were* an operator like `&&` or `||`, it would necessarily run both commands because the value of XOR is determined by both its operands (it doesn't short-circuit). The resulting exit status would be 0 if one command failed and the other succeed, or 1 otherwise. I can't really picture a scenario where that would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enter `command ^ anothercommand`, you are simply providing `command` with two arguments, `^` and `anothercommand`. There is no operator here. `anothercommand` will only run if `command` decides to treat that argument as a command name and attempt to run it.

Comment: can you provide an example of a command that accept ^ as an argument?

Comment: @AK_: Yes, for example `echo ^`

Answer (score 9):

As you can see in `man bash`, `^` is not used to separate commands, it's used inside arithmetic expressions.

```
$ echo $(( 5 ^ 9 ))
12
```

That's because

```
dec     bin
 5     0101
 9     1001
-----------
12     1100
```

Comment: I honestly thought, it will work based  on the exit code of the commands (XOR of return values of each command), based on OP's intentions, silly me!

Comment: ok but why is bash not complaining about it when I use it on commands?

Comment: It does for me: `$ id ^ ls
id: extra operand ‘ls’
Try 'id --help' for more information.
`

Comment: @choroba - that's the `id` command complaining about the operator; run `w ^ id` and you will get no error

Comment: @AK_: Yes, and you can also try `w % id` or `w +-+ id` or whatever. There's no user named `^`, so you get just the header back. There's no `^` operator in bash for commands.

Comment: In a slightly different context, `^` is a history expansion operator. Try `echo foo`, followed by `^foo^bar`

Comment: @chepner: True. It still doesn't connect commands, though. It can also be used to uppercase a variable value or negate a character class.

Comment: @chepner that's a great example!!! So, can I run the `anotehrcommand` if I execute: `command ^history_command^anothercommand` ?

Comment: @AK_ No, I was just pointing where `^` gets used outside of arithmetic expressions. It does not join two commands on a command line like `&&` or `||` does; `^foo^bar` is entirely equivalent to `!!:s/foo/bar/`. See the section entitle HISTORY EXPANSION in the man page.

Comment: If you want to run two commands on the same command line, you just separate them with a semicolon: `w; ls`, which runs `w`, waits for it to complete (regardless of its exit status), then runs `ls`.

Comment: @chepner yes I know that; but I'm looking into the XOR operator in commands as it might cause security issues :)

Comment: I don't see how a non-existent operator can cause security issues.